# Cannot get Foundation 6 to work with Google Maps

Tags: google-maps, zurb-foundation

I am in the process of converting my website to work with Foundation 6, but I am having trouble with the following form http://scottishherringhistory.uk/statistics/Creeks.html. 
The map disappears.

Comment: When I run it in the Webstorm debugger I get what are basically syntax errors in the text window associated with the following line:    https:
                        //maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/openhand_8_8.cur"), default; touch-action: none;">

Comment: When I say that the form stops working, what I mean is that the map disappears!

Answer (score 0):

I am pleased to say that I have now managed to resolve my problems without really being sure what caused them! I suspect that the order in which the scripts were declared may have had to do with it. In any case, I have now republished my website so the above url refers to a working example!